# How to seperate the varibles into two row and change the variable of other columns at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B,B1','C','2,3,5','F','G'],
                  ['h','X,X1','J','2,4,8','L','M'],['O','P','Q','2,4','S','T'],
                  ['U','V','W','3,6','Y','Z']], 
                  columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','col1_v2','col2_v2','col3_v2'])
```

[image]

*

```
It seems need two steps to complete but the pandas tutorial sometimes do not mention too much on to clear the data on both columns. 
We need to seperate one row into two rows when one column has two variable.
Meanwhile, the variable changed, it will effect another column respectively.
```

- One more thing is the other effected column,col2_v2, its first variable,2, which is fixed. Therefore, the effected numbers will be the next two character.

We could use the explode method to seperate the column. like https://cmsdk.com/python/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe.html

*But when the other column has a fixed character, then how to put the character in its space.*

```
In order to show how it look like.This is how it should turn out like this.
```

We see Row 0, in Col2 it is B, B1 and respectively the col1_v2, the value is 2, 3, 5. When Col2 changed, the col1_v2 will be altered. However, the first character 2 represented the position which means it will be fixed. So, in Col2 is B, then in the col1_v2 will carry 3. in Col2 is B1, Then in the col1_v2 will get 5.

In row2, there are X and X1, X will get 4, X1 will get 8. So in the new row, when we put X, we will get 2,4. When we get X1, we will get 2,8. for 2 represents the position, it will be fixed.

[image]

*How to make the variable separate into two lines? then, the value change at the same time.*

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: I add the clear picture.

Comment: What is the exact logic for `col1_v2`? take first value and iterate rest?

Comment: why you do not have 3,5 for the first one

Comment: yes, Chris. take the first value and iterate rest.

Comment: reply to BENY. because the first one is fixed position, the next 2 or 3 should seperate.

Answer (score 4):

Let us do modify then `explode`

```
df['col1_v2'] = [[x.split(',')[0]+',' + y for y in x.split(',')[1:]]  for x in df['col1_v2']]
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].str.split(',')
s = df.pop('col1_v2').explode().reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.explode('Col2').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(s)
 
df
  Col1 Col2 Col3 col2_v2 col3_v2 col1_v2
0    A    B    C       F       G     2,3
1    A   B1    C       F       G     2,5
2    h    X    J       L       M     2,4
3    h   X1    J       L       M     2,8
4    O    P    Q       S       T     2,4
5    U    V    W       Y       Z     3,6
```

Comment: The variable of X should turn to 2,4 and The variable of X1 should turn to 2, 8.

Comment: @YeiBi check the update

Comment: Yes, that is! Thank you very much!!

Comment: create a list of values and explode. simple as that. thx BENY